# SQL update on joined tables

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, oracle, odbc

I'm writing a small SQL Database browser. Requiered function is to select, update, insert,remove from two tables connected by a key. I've used OdbcAdapter to select from two tables and used bind to DataGrid, but OdbcCommandBuilder doesn't offer possibility to update contents when I'm using two connected tables.
How I can achieve this function when it has to work on any tables from any database (numbers of colums are not specified).

Is it possible to make suggestions for specific fields values concerning their possible values (possible values of foreign key).

Comment: Why can't you just create two update statements and put them in a transaction?

Answer (score 2):

An updatable view should provide this for you - Oracle does support these. Here is an example: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#i2126726

Comment: Hmm however this way I would have to create view on start and on next start check if view for them already exists or delete on exit. Is there any method for not only Oracle?

Comment: I doubt that there is a solution that will work in all cases as the action to take depends on the nature of the join - conceptually it only works when you have a join with a one-to-one mapping between the two tables, i.e. the row in the datagrid corresponds to a single row in each table and these table rows are not present in any other datagrid rows. For any other join updating a cell in the grid would result in values in other rows changing (which would be counter-intuitive for a user)

Comment: For example, say we were joining Employee to Department and the resulting row has employee_name and department_name in our datagrid. What would be the expected result if the user typed in a new value for department_name?  Update the name of the department? Update the employee to belong to a new department (creating a new department if one doesn't exist)?

Comment: I've checked this method - updatable view can not contain join.